# What is the "average time remaining" when guessing a random value?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I lack the terminology to ask this question "properly", so to illustrate what I'm bouncing around in my mind, let's take a story example:

> John wrote a script which guesses passwords. He has a list of *21,600 passwords*, of which one of them has been used for a login on a particular endpoint. If his computer is able to test *one password each second*, it will take the script an average time of *3 hours* to break in (with a maximum possible running time of *6 hours*).
>
> After the script has run for *two hours*, he observes that the script has not yet found the correct password and is still running.

I'm wondering two things:

1. Is the statement *"It will take the script an average time of 3 hours to break in"* correct? Is the average completion time in this scenario simply half of the total time?
2. When John checks on the script after it has been running for *2 hours*, will there be an average time of *1 hour* be remaining, or (if uncompleted so far), will there be an average time of *2 hours* remaining? `*`

`*` *2 hours* is the average time until the script has completed half of the script's remaining time at the point at which John checks it (i.e. half of *4 hours*)

Comment: As I said, I don't know much mathematical terminology beyond what is found in Geometry and basic Calculus, so please edit the tags or any wording as needed.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Half of 4 hours.

Comment: @Did: I could be mistaken, but I think (2) is a bit more subtle than that… it smells to me of a frequentist/Bayesian thing: is the password fixed and there is no randomness in this scenario, or is the password itself random because we do not have complete information? The half-of-4 answer seems to me to favor the Bayesian approach.

Comment: @EricStucky No. It is simply a discrete conditioning by the event [password not found in two first hours].

Answer (score 2):

The password is equally likely to be found in $1$ second, $2$ seconds, $3$  seconds, and so on up to $21600$ seconds. So if we let $n=21600$, the mean time is $\frac{1}{n}(1+2+\cdots+n)$. This is $(n+1)/2$, which is $3$ hours for all practical purposes,  but not *exactly* $3$ hours.

The same sort of minor correction applies to checking after $2$ hours. **Given** that the password has not been found, there are $(21600)(4/6)$ passwords to go, that is, $14400$. The mean additional time is $(14401)/2$ seconds, for all practical purposes $2$ hours.

The *unconditional* average time remaining after $2$ hours does not have a clear meaning. But it is reasonable to say it is $0$ with probability about $2/6$, and $2$ with probability about $4/6$, giving about $8/6$.